Unknown component in oil level sensor
An oil level sensor, on my 1999 model bus, broke and when I took it apart there were two components inside.
One reed switch and one component in series that I have trouble identifying.
I have tried to measure it but it seems broken, OL on ohms and diode.
It looks like it has the color code red, orange and gold. And from that I found it could be a 2.3 ohms resistor.
The only problem with that is the housing of the sensor is labelled 24v 3 watts, and 2.3 ohms at 24vdc is closer to 250 watt.
And I don't understand what else it could be than a resistor, but I need to be sure.
I have talked to a mechanic but he was not sure either.
The component is 5.6mm long and 1.88-2.1mm thick, I don't see any clear markings, maybe the number 3 on the edge.
The whole sensor is a vdo low level switch, marked 462/2/1 and 3018456, but I didn't find any concrete information that could tell me what this component could be.
What kind of component could this be, and what value would it have?


What resistance does it measure?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany OL/overload/nothing

Potential avenues of investigation, with no knowledge of how this sensor works: A fusible resistor that's done its job and fused (i.e. blown open); some kind of thermal fuse that's overheated and fused; a capacitor which wouldn't measure anything on ohms or diode mode anyway; back-to-back zeners that are too high voltage for your meter to measure. || It's probably not a resistor, as resistor color codes rarely if ever use only three bands; four and five bands are common, and six for some specialty parts, but never three. Some capacitor color codes do use three bands, though.

It may have had more color rings that fell off. Could be a safety resistor of some kohm to avoid high currents in an inflammable environment.

it may make more sense to post at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Look up the schematic online. There are many third-party companies that publish them, such as Audels, https://www.worldradiohistory.com/BOOKSHELF-ARH/Audels-Electric-Library.htm, if you cannot get one from the manufacturer.

@John-Arvid Well, that's no help. Maybe a resistor to help keep the reed from getting sticky. If it's in series it might not be expected to have much voltage across it even with the reed capsule conducting. If it got shorted then the part could have opened.

A thermistor perhaps? Some come with peculiar color coding.
